# accessing input inside the form using jquery

Tags: jquery, forms, input

```
<form id='test_form' name='test_form'>
<input type='hidden' name='test_input' value='0' />
</form>

<form id='test_form_2' name='test_form_2'>
<input type='hidden' name='test_input' value='0' />
</form>
```

I need to change value of test_input inside the test_form_2
Is there one line straight code for that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#test_form_2 input[name="test_input"]').val('whatever');
```